# Discord.js v12 get total number of channels that your bot is in

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

So `eval(bot.guilds.cache.map(g => g.memberCount).join(' + '));` gets the total number of discord users that are in the same guild as your bot, how do I get the total number of channels in all the guilds that my bot has access to?

Comment: I've never seen anyone doing that kind of stuff with `eval`, mostly because it results in horrible performance.

Comment: Use `bot.guilds.cache.reduce((a, g) => a+g.memberCount)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```js
bot.channels.cache.size
```

Comment: Thank you that ie what I was looking for